# Confused concerning RDF knowledge graphs

Tags: rdf, presentation, knowledge-graph

I have a question concerning a presentation topic in information retrieval masters course. The topic of my presentation is about "RDF knowledge graphs". I wanna ask is there a difference between a normal/basic knowledge graph and the RDF graph? and can anyone please write me a brief explanation about that?

P.S.: I am new to the topic

Comment: It seems that you're asking us to do your homework. That doesn't help anyone. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Knowledge graph is just a generic non standard phrase introduced more or less a few years ago. RDF is a proper W3C standardized language. So, all we can say is that "an RDF knowledge graph is a knowledge graph in RDF language", right? Nto sure what you want to hear. Some people call knowledge graph their dataset in a graph database, some other is it for different things.

Comment: AKSW... big thanks.. Yes this explanation is what i need.